# Cant seem to load vuejs component, TypeError: "this.kitChens.find(...) is undefined"

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

What I intend to achieve is to display a different image on select change from the list of options loaded via an API on Axios

The Vue Component Code

```html
<template>
  <div class="row my-3 p-75">
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 container-fluid rounded-pill ">
      <div class="content-body rounded-pill">
        <section id="description" class="card rounded-pill">
          <div class="card-content rounded-pill ">
            <img class="-block w-100" :src="'/../../images/'+ kitchenImage()"
              :alt="'{{ kitChen.kitchen_type}}'" />
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 zindex-1 ">
      <h4 class="card-title"> Choose your Kitchen configuration</h4>
      <select class="form-control-lg rounded-pill primary" id="basicSelect" v-model="selectedKitchen"
        @change="getKitchen()">
        <option value="0">Choose your Kitchen configuration</option>
        <option v-for="kitChen in kitChens" :value="kitChen.id" v-bind:key="kitChen.id">
          {{ kitChen.kitchen_type }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      console.log('Component mounted.')
      this.getKitchen('1');
    },
    directives: {
      init: {
        bind(el) {
          el.value = el.getAttribute("value");
          el.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
        }
      }
    },
    computed: {
      kitchenImage() {
        return (
          this.kitChens.find(el => el.id == this.selectedKitchen).kitchen_type_pic || "");
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        kitChens: [],
        selectedKitchen: 0, // set default section to 'home'

      };
    },
    props: {
      estateid: String,
      houseid: String,
    },
    methods: {
      getKitchen: function () {
        axios.get("/api/getKitchen", {
            params: {
              estate_id: this.estateid,
              house_type_id: this.houseid,
            }
          })
          .then(
            function (response) {
              this.kitChens = response.data;
            }.bind(this)
          );
      },
      created: function () {
        this.getKitchen();
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

I keep on getting

> error "[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.kitChens.find(...) is undefined"" which is causing the component is not rendering.

This is how I load the component

```html
<kitchen-component estateid="2" houseid="3"></kitchen-component>
```

I will be grateful for any help

Comment: `kitChens` is initially empty, so it won't find anything. If nothing is found it will return `undefined`. You can't read the property `kitchen_type_pic` of `undefined`.

Comment: Help with editing the code, newbie here pls thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems here...

Firstly, `kitChen` with a capital `C` in the middle? I don't know why you've done that but any future maintainers of your code will appreciate you sticking to correct spelling and standard use of capital letters.

Likewise you need to sort out your indentation. It's all over the place. While it may not prevent the code from working it does prevent other developers from being able to understand it.

The next problem is your `kitchenImage` property. Initially the array `kitChens` will be empty, so it won't find anything. `find` will return `undefined` and then the attempt to access the property `kitchen_type_pic` will fail. You need something like this:

```js
computed: {
  kitchenImage() {
    const kitchen = this.kitChens.find(el => el.id == this.selectedKitchen)

    return kitchen && kitchen.kitchen_type_pic
  }
}
```

Here I've assumed it is acceptable for `kitchenImage` to be `undefined`.

Then there are several problems in your template:

```html
<img class="-block w-100" :src="'/../../images/' + kitchenImage()" :alt="'{{ kitChen.kitchen_type}}'" />
```

`kitchenImage` is a computed property, not a method, so you don't need the `()` on the end. It'll also need a `v-if` to handle the case where `kitchenImage` is `undefined`. It may be that it makes more sense for that `v-if` to be higher up, it's difficult for me to know what the correct behaviour should be in that case.

There's also the problem of the `alt`. I'm not even sure what that's trying to do.

I think you're aiming for something like this:

```html
<img
  v-if="kitchenImage"
  class="-block w-100"
  :src="'/../../images/' + kitchenImage"
  :alt="kitChen.kitchen_type"
/>
```

However, for this to work it will need `kitChen.kitchen_type` to exist and I don't see anything in your original code to suggest that it does. I suspect what you want is a similar computed property to `kitchenImage` that returns the `kitchen_type` instead of the `kitchen_type_pic`.

Comment: Yes you're correct, I have implemented the corrections and it works perfectly. and i had to change the kitChen to kitchen.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling kitchenImage() on template load.

Which runs your Find() function, which then in return will try to find a select kitty with the ID of 0, which i assume is undefined.

The solution is:

Set a default 'selectedKitchen' value.

Or..

structure your code so your function doesnt run untill a kitty has actually been  selected. This can be done but changing your computed function to a method. Then running it Onclick https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

> Special note: I thought it was kitty's this whole time reading the
> code and not, kitchen, but im going to leave this in

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i tried and it still not working.Could you help with code edit